# Karma test running on Bitbucket pipeline gives error "can't find variable angular (and module)"

Tags: karma-runner, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to get the Bitbucket pipeline working for my MEAN stack application.

So I cloned the MEAN stack framework to my Bitbucket https://github.com/linnovate/mean and added the following bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
# This is a sample build configuration for JavaScript.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/14UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: node:6.9.4

definitions: 
  services: 
    mongo: 
      image: mongo

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm install
          - npm test
        services: 
          - mongo
        deployment: test
```

But when I run the test I get the following error message (see pastebin https://pastebin.com/TY6sBigB):

```
[36m06 03 2019 04:18:12.764:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]: [39mReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular

  http://localhost:9876/base/modules/users/client/views/settings/settings.client.view.html.js?7d60b7bc1406b1321039f3ea5f1c798982967142:5

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module in modules/articles/tests/client/list-articles.client.controller.tests.js (line 34)
  modules/articles/tests/client/list-articles.client.controller.tests.js:34:22
  <Jasmine>
  modules/articles/tests/client/list-articles.client.controller.tests.js:4:11
  <Jasmine>

Finished in 0.041 secs / 0 secs @ 04:18:12 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

The missing 'module' error seems to show up at (admin.articles.client.routes.tests.js):

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  describe('Articles Route Tests', function () {
    // Initialize global variables
    var $scope,
      ArticlesService;

    // We can start by loading the main application module
    beforeEach(module(ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName));
```

The 'module' variable is a global variable defined in the @Types module, but I'm not sure how this could cause the error.

The missing 'angular' variable happens in: (articles.client.service.js)

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('articles.services')
    .factory('ArticlesService', ArticlesService);
```

Which is a namespace defined in the angular typescript file: `export as namespace angular;`

This is my karma config file:
https://pastebin.com/MVYyXAzV

And my package.json:
https://pastebin.com/GEvTSi2A

Answer (score 0):

You need to add angular to your package.json file.
try `npm install angular` then commit your package.json and push to your repo.

Will probably look something like this

```
40   "dependencies": {                                                             
41     "acl": "^0.4.11",                                                           
42     "amazon-s3-uri": "0.0.3",                                                   
43     "angular": "^1.7.7",                                                    
44     "angular-mocks": "^1.7.7",                                                
45     "async": "~2.5.0",                                                   
46     "aws-sdk": "^2.415.0",                                                   
47     "body-parser": "^1.18.3",                                                   
48     "bower": "^1.8.8",
```

in your package.json

Any time you see messages like this you will know that you are missing a dependency or you aren't defining a variable somewhere.

In this case we know it is a missing dependency because there is no mention of angular in your custom code for karma and we have to assume the karma test runner works, or why would anyone recommend it.

FYI, a lot of your dependencies look like dev dependencies, like bower for example, and you probably shouldn't put them in a production environment for various reasons including total cost of hosting.  You only want bitbucket pipelines to push files necessary for your app to run after being built to your production server.

The end goal is usually the smallest amount of code needed to run the app living in production and dev dependencies just build and test that code.

For example bower is essentially a package manager just like npm, but once it downloads all of the packages, bower can be thrown away, while keeping the bower_components folder in production.  Obviously you could also create scripts to pare down your bower_components into files with just the parts you need,and throw away the bower_components folder, preserving just the minimum on production.

Hope that helps in some way.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time (and the tips you gave). I tried adding angular but unfortunately the same error shows up. When I run the tests locally everything works fine indeed. I've updated the question with some more details. Could it be Typescript related? As that is where the missing variables come from.

Comment: Yes, if you have typescript installed globally on your machine, and it doesn't exist in your package.json, the docker image on bitbucket pipelines doesn't know to download it.

If you ran this command on your computer a long time ago
`npm install -g typescript`

It won't show up in your package.json file because you installed it globally on your computer. You also would not be able to run your project on another computer unless it has typescript installed.